# Ant Design: How can I disable border-bottom of a menu item on hover?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux, antd

I want to modify the default style of a Menu Item (which has a Search Bar inside it), I want to remove the border-bottom property which is appeared by hovering over the item (search bar)

```
<Menu theme='light' className='nav-bar' mode='horizontal'>
      <Menu.Item disabled style={{ color: '#262626', fontSize: '1.5rem' }}>
        {/* <Title style={{color: '#40a9ff'}} level={4}>Dokan</Title> */}
        Dokan
      </Menu.Item>

      <Menu.Item className="modified-item">
        <Search
          placeholder='input search text'
          onSearch={(value) => console.log(value)}
        />
      </Menu.Item>

      <Menu.Item className>Change Theme</Menu.Item>

      <Menu.Item className>Home</Menu.Item>

      <Menu.Item className>Checkout</Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
```

what I have tried is:

```
.modified-item:hover {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Instead of assigning class to Menu item, assign it to search box. Then apply the css. See if it works

Comment: applied but didn't work.

Comment: Try with `!important`. If still didnt work then check in dev tools why it is appearing

Answer (score 3):

```
.ant-menu-horizontal > .ant-menu-item::after,
.ant-menu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu::after {
  border-bottom: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`border-bottom: none;` is not a style option that exists in css.
try
`border-bottom-style: none;`
or
`opacity: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using className in Menu.Item use style property

```
<Menu.Item style={{borderBottom:'none'}}>
    <Search
      placeholder='input search text'
      onSearch={(value) => console.log(value)}
    />
</Menu.Item>
```

Comment: this is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
.ant-menu-item:hover::after {
  border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

This will work

Answer (score 0):

Add Style to Your Menu Tag as below

```
<Menu
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        selectedKeys={[current]}
        mode="horizontal"
        className="pb-3 pl-3 pt-3"
        style={{borderBottom: "none", lineHeight:"0px"}}
      >
```